# Хостинг скриптов js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть необходимость написать сайт, но нужно где-то хранить все скрипты и стили(`js`, `css`).
Хостинг и доменное имя не очень хочется мутить. Возможно есть какие-то сервисы, где можно залить скрипт, и использовать его URL в теге `src`?

Comment: хм.... а где сам сайт будет?  Не проще было бы эти файлы хранить там же?
или вам просто надо где - то эти файлы сохранить, чтобы не потерять? ))))

Comment: Просто большинство сайтов будут идентичные, на разных хостах.
А скрипты будут модульные, поэтому нет смысла их дублировать

Comment: не понимаю если честно того что вы хотите... не понимаю Зачем. если на одном стороннем ресурсе будет зависание или он временно пропадет то - плакали все ваши сайты. но судя по тому что вы называете - 

> Хостинг и доменное имя не очень
> хочется мутить


могу четко и точно сказать - хотите просто заражать сторонние сайты JS скриптом и не хотите палиться.

Comment: Вы извините, но Вы не адекватны в этом вопросе. Речь идёт о модульности. Тот же принцип DRY, только мне нужно было реализовать что то вроде сборника модулей. Первый комментарий мне очень помог, тот что связан с ДропБоксом.
Про яндекс хранилище библиотек я уже слышал.
А вот насчёт заражать, то Вы скорее не понимаете концепцию js. Как возможно заразить сторонний ресурс, из скрипта, который работает на другом? Здесь действует политика безопасности, работы на одном и том же доменном имени. Подключать можно откуда угодно, а вот работать скрипт может только с тем доменом, где он подключен.
Спасибо!

Comment: + если у меня есть доступ к добавлению тега <script>, то это либо доступ ftp, либо доступ через админ-панель сайта. В обоих случаях я могу спокойно править php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй на дропбоксе

Answer (score 2):

Самые популярные библиотеки уже хостятся на [Яндекс](http://api.yandex.ru/jslibs/) или [Google](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

sf.net, google code, github, narod.ru, и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

А в src почему не прописать абсолютный адрес? Есть определённый сайт(site_1.ru), на котором лежат библиотеки, есть другой сайт(site_2.ru), на котором не лежит ничего, но скрипт подгружается так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site_1.ru/scripts/script_1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Сайтов очень много, и не хотелось бы повторять одно и тоже, заливать всё то же самое

Comment: Вы ответ читали? Человек и говорит о том что заливать тоже самое на все хосты не надо, залить только раз, на первый.

Comment: когда я отвечал на вопрос, он звучал несколько по другому.

Answer (score 0):

https://surge.sh/ - попробуй этот сервис

> Simple, single-command web publishing. Publish HTML, CSS, and JS for
>   free, without leaving the command line.